# Setting exit value from Chapel

Tags: chapel

Is it possible to set the exit status when terminating a Chapel program?
I can always use:

```
extern "exit" proc c_exit(status:c_int);
```

The following does the trick.

```
extern "exit" proc c_exit(status:c_int);


module M {

    proc main() {

        writeln("hello, world");
        c_exit(1);
    }
}
```

This sets the exit status to 1 - just wondering if there's a way that doesn't require a call into the C library.

Comment: Are the `extern "atoi"` procedures related?  I'm not seeing the connection between them and the `c_exit` call

Comment: I assume that this was a cut-and-paste error, and have updated the extern procedure calls to what I expect was intended.

Comment: Yup - a copy-n-paste error.  Thanks for the fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just call exit(1). See proc exit in [chapel docs](https://chapel-lang.org/docs/builtins/UtilMisc_forDocs.html#UtilMisc_forDocs.exit) .

Comment: Moreover, you _should_ do this.  Calling C's exit() isn't guaranteed to tear Chapel programs down cleanly (particularly when running in distributed memory) while Chapel's exit() ought to.

Comment: I was looking in the spec and didn't see the exit function.  I'm good now.  Thanks.